# Java JTable changing icon in cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

This has been asked a million times it appears, but I must be feeling especially dense tonight because I'm still having trouble. My first question is this, when I call

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/x.jpg"));
```

where is it looking for the images folder? I've tried making it a folder under my project and under src. What am I missing? I'm using Eclipse. As you've probably guessed already, I haven't done much Java.

What I really want to do is to set the the first column in a table to an initial icon and then allow the user to double click on it and change the icon. Could someone be so kind as to gently push (or violently shove) me in the right direction? Do I need my own renderer class?

```
class MyRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
....
```

When someone double clicks on the row I want to change the icon to y.jpg.

**Edited**
Thanks for the help. Another dumb question. Should I see the icon when I add a row like this?

```
DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel)tblNews.getModel();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/x.jpg"));
dm.addRow(new Object[]{icon, "Text"});
```

I see the filename of the icon, but not the icon itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) your ImageIcon could be placed for 
(`new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("images/x.jpg"));`)

- src

  - MyPackage

    ```
         - MyClass.java
    ```
  - MyPackage/images

    ```
               - x.jpg
    ```

more [Packaging](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html) in Java

2) [JTable knows Icon / ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) as Object, then there no reason set for [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) in the Renderer

Comment: +1 TO add. Just check in compiled classes folder whether the x.jpg is copied there.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I edited my original question. Can I use addRow with an icon?

Answer (score 3):

In order to make images folder in your project, you need to first Right-Click your Project, and then Select `Source Folder` (not Folder), then name this Source Folder as `images`. Now manually add your Images to this folder by moving through the `File System`. Once done, go back to your Eclipse, `Refresh` your project, you be able to see your `images` `Source Folder` in the `Project Tree`.

Now in order to access the images write this for your `ImageIcon` :

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/x.jpg"));
```

Do remember the first Forward Slash before your actual image inside the `images Source Folder`. Now Run your project and check your `bin folder`, your image will be automatically added to this area.

Try this code, I had tested it and it is working flawless. I can see Images inside the JTable too, with this code.

```
package jtable;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JFrame
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        ImageIcon backIcon = getImage("/images/bac.png");
        ImageIcon exitIcon = getImage("/images/exit.png");
        ImageIcon forwardIcon = getImage("/images/forward.png");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {backIcon, "BACK"},
            {exitIcon, "EXIT"},
            {forwardIcon, "FORWARD"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable( model )
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    private ImageIcon getImage(String path)
    {
        java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
        if (url != null)
            return (new ImageIcon(url));
        else
        {
            System.out.println(url);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TableIcon frame = new TableIcon();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }  
}
```

Here is the output :

[image: JTable Image] and Here is the link to my project [JTable Project](http://www.4shared.com/zip/mOqkmxyI/JTableTest.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'd vote up your response, but I don't have the reputation yet. If you have any thoughts about why I'm seeing the filename rather than the icon I would appreciate it.

Comment: @nickfinity : I don't know much about JTable though, give me sometime, I will read the tutorials and will tell you, if I catch something. Sorry for the late reply. That was night time, when you replied.

Comment: @nickfinity : Do check this code I had just pasted, this might can help you to see images :-)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I sincerely appreciate your help. I'll check it out in the morning here.

Comment: @nickfinity : Now I learned you can write, what you asked in your Edited Question Part.  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/appIcon.png"));
        model.addRow(new Object[]{icon, "Text"});, this will work too :-) Keep Smiling

Comment: I must have been doing something incorrectly when I was adding the row. I thought that's how I had it. I'll try again. Thanks again.

Comment: @nickfinity : Use this model.addRow(new Object[]{icon, "Text"});, in my code that I had given after you done making JTable table = new JTabel(model){} part. Then it will add the row, the way you were doing. Do try to download the Project that I had given in the link. :-)